# tmux binding a key to bash command refuses to work

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, configuration, tmux

I want to be able to respawn all panes in my current window that are NOT in tree-mode.
I made this script and it works:

```
for i in $(tmux list-panes -F "#{line} #{pane_id} #{pane_mode} #{pane_active}" | sort -k3 | grep -v tree-mode | awk '{print$2}'); do tmux respawn-pane -k -t $i; done
```

I want to bind this to tmux-action + `R` key. But it wont work.

I tried the following:

```
bind-key R send-keys "for i in $(tmux list-panes -F "#{line} #{pane_id} #{pane_mode} #{pane_active}" | sort -k3 | grep -v tree-mode | awk '{print$2}'); do tmux respawn-pane -k -t $i; done"
bind-key R run-shell "for i in $(tmux list-panes -F "#{line} #{pane_id} #{pane_mode} #{pane_active}" | sort -k3 | grep -v tree-mode | awk '{print$2}'); do tmux respawn-pane -k -t $i; done" Enter
```

I also tried putting the script into a file and adding the following to `.tmux.conf`

```
bind-key R run-shell "./tmux_respawn.sh"
```

But I get a 127 error an not sure why. If I run the script from my current pane I dont get and error and it works.

I tried building an alias as well in my ~/.bashrc, which works fine from shell, but I get a shell 127 error when trying to run it via a bind key.

```
alias RespawnTmuxPanes='for i in $(/usr/local/bin/tmux list-panes -F "#{line} #{pane_id} #{pane_mode} #{pane_active}" | sort -k3 | grep -v tree-mode | awk '{print$2}'); do /usr/local/bin/tmux respawn-pane -k -t $i; done'
```

I really don't want to have a separate file for this script, I want to run it directly from `.tmux.conf` with a binded key, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to run the script directly inside of `~/.tmux.conf` and built the script as a separate file that I had tmux run.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_id} #{pane_mode} #{pane_active}' -f '#{?#{m:tree-mode,#{pane_mode}},0,1}' | sort -k2 | cut -f1 -d' '); do tmux respawn-pane -k -t $i; done
```

Note: I found a way to use `-f` with tmux to filter out the tree-mode panes so I did not need to use `awk`.

Here is the entry in my tmux file:

```
bind-key R run-shell "/home/mradmin/.tmux_respawn_screens.sh"
```

This works, as I can now do TMUX-ACTION + `R`, and it respawns all my panes that are not in tree mode and does the active pane I am in last.

Answer (score 0):

This would likely best be done by calling an external script (probably
with a fully qualified path, e.g. `/home/user/libexec/tmux-foo`) as
otherwise one must deal with a layered nest of `tmux`, `sh`, and `awk`
interpolation and quoting rules. Fun!

Also the command is too complicated, especially given that it is broken
in several ways, most notably that the internal `"` must all be escaped
with `\"`, and maybe some of the `$variables` also need `\$variable`
escaping to protect them from `tmux` interpolation.

So we need something simple, and a means to reload the `tmux`
configuration to ensure that we get the new configuration, and to
confirm that `tmux` does not yell at us about one of the many typos that
you will make (unless you make less typos than I do). Also I already
have `R` for reload so I put the special command on `W`, which you might
want to change around.

```
bind-key R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "source-file done"
bind-key W run-shell "tmux list-panes -F \"#{pane_id} #{pane_mode}\" >> SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX"
```

With this in place we can then run `R` `W` and confirm there are no
syntax errors `tmux` reports, and then find the `SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX`
file, which may be under your home directory, or otherwise should be
fairly easy to find. In another terminal, we can watch this file as we
fiddle around with the `tmux` configuration:

```
tail -f SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX
```

I've also simplified the `tmux` command as `#{line}` was or was not
present depending on how I ran the `tmux` command, and columns that move
around make selecting the right column with `awk` a little difficult.
Also `grep ... | awk ...` can usually be reduced to just a more
complicated `awk ...` expression, which shortens our command and saves
some CPU time.

```
bind-key W run-shell "tmux list-panes -F \"#{pane_id} #{pane_mode}\" | awk '!/tree-mode/{print $1}' >> SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX"
```

Be sure to test with `R` `W` often in `tmux`; trying to do the whole
thing at once is complicated. Testing after each new shell command lets
you know if you're on the right track or not. The above excludes the
`tree-mode` stuff.

```
bind-key W run-shell "tmux list-panes -F \"#{pane_id} #{pane_mode}\" | awk '!/tree-mode/{print $1}' | while read id; do echo $id >> SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX; done"
```

Whoops, the output file is empty. `tmux` apparently does something with
the unquoted `$id`, so we quote it with `\$id`

```
bind-key W run-shell "tmux list-panes -F \"#{pane_id} #{pane_mode}\" | awk '!/tree-mode/{print $1}' | while read id; do echo \$id >> SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX; done"
```

but `\$id` in turn must be quoted to prevent a POSIX shell from doing
crazy things with it otherwise, but not single-quoted, because we do
need the shell to interpolate it:

```
bind-key W run-shell "tmux list-panes -F \"#{pane_id} #{pane_mode}\" | awk '!/tree-mode/{print $1}' | while read id; do echo \"\$id\" >> SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX; done"
```

Anyways, following this method it should be possible to add the other
`tmux` variables back in, and then to get the `sort` command working
correctly, and only after the `echo` results look good replace the
caveman debugging (printing output to a file) with the actual `tmux`
command to be run:

```
... while read id; do tmux respawn-pane -k -t \"\$id\"; done
```

Or you could do this in an external script, which gives you a file
that's a bit easier to test and does not run afoul `tmux` and `sh` and
`awk` interpolation and escaping rules.

Comment: Thank you for spending the time to put this post together. Couple problems I am running into. First of all, I agree, didn't need "#{line}" that can be removed (left that in there by accident). But I do need `sort -k2` for sorting the active_pane for it to be at the bottom (now `-k2` as "#{line}" was removed). If omitted, the list of pane numbers may have the pane I am running it in, in the middle of processing, which will stop the script from running and not complete respawning the other panes, my active pane needs to be the last pane respawned.

Comment: Lastly, I am not seeing the same results when running `bind-key R run-shell "tmux list-panes -F \"#{pane_id} #{pane_mode} #{pane_active}\" > SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX"` in `.tmux.conf`. It shows the last row of output for the command multiple times for the number of panes I have. If I run the same command in a sperate terminal this does not happen. Expected? With that being said your advice is helpful, maybe I can try getting all escape characters working properly.

Comment: Side note. there is a `-f` filter parameter that can be used with list-panes. I have no idea how it works as I cant find much documentation on it. Can I use this somehow to avoid using grep/awk?

Comment: `> SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX` is very different from the `>> SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX` I used. I also saw different results from exactly where I ran the `tmux` commands from (e.g. under `run-shell` in `tmux.conf` or in a shell under `tmux`. This probably makes things trickier.

Comment: Ok. I tried using `> SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX` instead of `>> SOMEOUTPUTFROMTMUX` Same thing happens. Its just the first entry repeated for as many panes as I have.